# Can DA4R connect to a database?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation

I have succeeded in creating an appbundle that saves information about a document to a JSON file.
I tried using the same appbundle to connect and save the document information to an external Mongodb database, but received a connection error. I tried whitelisting all the IPs to allow connections to the database, but failed again.

Can I use DA4R to connect to an external database and read/write data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I use DA4R to connect to an external database and read/write data?

No, you cannot access internet from the D4R appbundles.

Best workaround I can suggest is to handle this as a post process to your workitem. After your workitem finishes, you may analyze the JSON output and update the database from your server.